# What Actions can I do with my Things?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

According to the manual, Things can do actions in battle like other cards, and even support other actions. So what actions can I do when playing my Thing cards in battle? What are the button timings?

Answer (score 1):

Thing cards, while most of them do damage, also have extra effects, especially in boss battles. For example, the Balloon, which normally takes out enemies by floating them away, can be used to pull one of the bosses out of the water so that you can attack them. The Instant Camera helps you avoid another's Instakill combination, as the copy would be the one snagged by the neck. The Washing Machine is especially helpful in the final dungeon, as it would wash away the black paint one boss fires off as a last resort kind of thing. And then there's the Gro... I mean, the Disco Ball, which doesn't do damage, but causes your enemies to dance, making them skip a turn.

A few can blind your enemies, like the Salt and Pepper, while the Compass lets you flee from a fight (excluding boss fights) as two more examples.

There is also a way to do more by hitting A at the right time(s) during a Thing animation. For example, with the Lucky Cat, you hit A whenever it slams into the ground.

Comment: Feel free to add in the other Thing effects.

Comment: I know about the side effects like that, I used the fire extinguisher in the fight against Morton to great effect. But is there a button timing?

Comment: From what I have seen, yes. Although I do not know the timings off hand for most of them.

Comment: As a general rule, the guy in the trash can will tell you what Thing you can use against a boss. As far as I can tell, both Things and their replicas have the same effect in battles.